# Grouping of data with certain criteria

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

I have a following data frame of user stats:

```
ID    User      VisitTime
1     Ra          08:00
1     Ma          15:13
2     Da          20:15
2     La          11:00
```

How do I create  a datafram ewith another column named as "label" to show time in Morning, Afternoon and Evening?
 I referred some of the posts on Stackoverflow and used `dplyr` `group_by` but not able to produce desire results.

Basically I am looking for this  data frames:

```
ID    User      VisitTime    Label
1     Ra          08:00      Morning 
1     Ma          15:13      Evening
2     Da          20:15      Night
2     La          11:00      Morning
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert `VisitTime` to `POSIXct` format, extract `hour` from it, define "Morning", "Afternoon", "Evening" and "Night" and assign labels.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(time = as.POSIXct(VisitTime, format = "%H:%M"), 
         hour = as.integer(format(time, '%H')), 
         Label  = case_when(between(hour, 6, 11) ~ "Morning", 
                            between(hour, 12, 15) ~"Afternoon", 
                            between(hour, 16, 19) ~"Evening", 
                            TRUE ~"Night"))
```